# Speed up operations on a for loop with `coo` matrix and a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scipy

I have a numpy array and a `coo` matrix.  I need to update the numpy array based on elements in the `coo` matrix.  Both the numpy array and the matrix are very large, here is what they look like:

```
 graph_array = [[  1.0   1.0   5.0  9.0]
 [  2.0   5.0   6.0   5.0]
 [  3.0   5.0   7.0   6.0]]

matrix_coo = (1, 5) 0.5
(2, 8)  0.4
(5, 7)  0.8
```

What I need to do is as follows:

If the second and third element in each list within the array i.e. `list_graph[i][1][2]` (which could be `1,5`, `5,6` or `5,7`)  is equal to a row and column pair in the `coo` matrix such as `(1, 5), (2, 8) or (5, 7)` then the value associated with that pair (for `(1, 5)` this equals `0.5`) must replace the fourth element in the list within the array.

My expected output would thus be:

```
output_array = [[  1.0   1.0   5.0  0.5]
[  2.0   5.0   6.0   5.0]
[  3.0   5.0   7.0   0.8]]
```

The current code I am using is as follows:

```
 row_idx = list(matrix_coo.row)
 col_idx = list(matrix_coo.col)
 data_idx = list(matrix_coo.data)

x = 0
    while x < len(row_cost_idx):
        for m in graph_array:
            if m[1] == row_idx[x]:
                if m[2] == col_idx[x]:
                    m[3] = data_idx[x]
        x += 1
```

It does give me the correct output but because the array has 21596 items and the matrix has 21596 rows it takes a very long time.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: The list and matrix names are messed up. Further you explain array, where is that used? Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I've made changes in the code I provided.  Are you referring to `graph_array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration is a pure Python list operation.  The fact that `row_idx` originated as an attribute of a `coo_matrix` doesn't apply

It could be cleaned up a bit with:

What is `row_cost_idx`?  If it is the same as `row_idx` we could do

```
for r,c,d in zip(matrix_coo.row, matrix_coo.col, matrix_coo.data):
    for m in graph_array: # not list_graph?
        if m[:2]==[r,c]:
            m[3] = d
```

I think the iteration is the same, but haven't tested it.  I'm not sure about speed either.

The double iteration, over nonzero elements of `matrix_coo` and sublists of `graph_array` is bound to be slow, simply because you are doing very many iterations.

If `graph_array` was a `numpy` `array`, we can test all rows at once, with something like

```
mask = (graph_array[:, :2]==[r,c]).all(axis=1)
graph_array[mask,3] = d
```

where `mask` would have 1's for the rows of `graph_array` that have the right indexes.  (again this isn't tested)

To get more speed I'd cast both `graph_array` and `matrix_coo` as 2d numpy (dense) arrays, and see if I can solve the problem with a few array operations.  Insights from that might help me replace the `matrix_coo` iteration.

=========================

Tested code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

graph_array = np.array([[  1.0,   1.0,   5.0 , 9.0],
 [  2.0,   5.0 ,  6.0  , 5.0],
 [  3.0  , 5.0 ,  7.0 ,  6.0]])

r,c,d = [1,2,5], [5,8,7],[0.5,0.4,0.8]
matrix_coo = sparse.coo_matrix((d,(r,c)))

def org(graph_array, matrix_coo):
    row_idx = list(matrix_coo.row)
    col_idx = list(matrix_coo.col)
    data_idx = list(matrix_coo.data)

    x = 0
    while x < len(row_idx):
        for m in graph_array:
            if m[1] == row_idx[x]:
                if m[2] == col_idx[x]:
                    m[3] = data_idx[x]
        x += 1
    return graph_array

new_array = org(graph_array.copy(), matrix_coo)    
print(graph_array)
print(new_array)

def alt(graph_array, matrix_coo):
    for r,c,d in zip(matrix_coo.row, matrix_coo.col, matrix_coo.data):
        for m in graph_array: 
            if (m[[1,2]]==[r,c]).all():  # array test
                m[3] = d
    return graph_array

new_array = alt(graph_array.copy(), matrix_coo)    
print(new_array)

def altlist(graph_array, matrix_coo):
    for r,c,d in zip(matrix_coo.row, matrix_coo.col, matrix_coo.data):
        for m in graph_array:
            if (m[1:3]==[r,c]):   # list test
                m[3] = d
    return graph_array

new_array = altlist(graph_array.tolist(), matrix_coo)    
print(new_array)

def altarr(graph_array, matrix_coo):
    for r,c,d in zip(matrix_coo.row, matrix_coo.col, matrix_coo.data):
        mask = (graph_array[:, 1:3]==[r,c]).all(axis=1)
        graph_array[mask,3] = d
    return graph_array

new_array = alt(graph_array.copy(), matrix_coo)    
print(new_array)
```

run

```
0909:~/mypy$ python3 stack3727173.py 
[[ 1.  1.  5.  9.]
 [ 2.  5.  6.  5.]
 [ 3.  5.  7.  6.]]
[[ 1.   1.   5.   0.5]
 [ 2.   5.   6.   5. ]
 [ 3.   5.   7.   0.8]]
[[ 1.   1.   5.   0.5]
 [ 2.   5.   6.   5. ]
 [ 3.   5.   7.   0.8]]
[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.5], [2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.0], [3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 0.80000000000000004]]
[[ 1.   1.   5.   0.5]
 [ 2.   5.   6.   5. ]
 [ 3.   5.   7.   0.8]]
```

For this small example, your function is fastest.  It also works with both list and array.  For small stuff list operations are often faster than array ones.  So using array operations to just compare 2 numbers is not an improvement.

replicating `graph_array` 1000x the `altarr` version is 10x faster than your code.  It's performing array operations on the largest dimension.  I haven't tried to increase the size of `matrix_coo`.

Comment: thanks! I'm testing the first neatened up solution and am getting the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` will try the conversion of graph_array and matrix_coo to dense arrays now.

Comment: Check the expression in the `if`.  `==` with lists or tuples should produce a scalar true/false and work.  But comparing numpy arrays produces a boolean array and this error.

Comment: Apologies! I didn't tell you that it was the `if ==` statement.  And I've just realized that `graph_array` is indeed a numpy array.  Will edit the question.

Comment: the `mask = (graph_array[:, :2]==[r,c]).all(axis=1)
graph_array[mask,3] = d` speeds it up significantly, thanks a lot!

Comment: After double checking, `mask` is an array that's purely made up of `False`.

Comment: Just replace my `:2` with `1:3`.  In my haste I just assumed you were testing the 1st 2 columns, not the 2nd 2 (1 and 2).